# Remove all the keys (credentials) from a PC

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, credentials, rsa

I gonna have to change my Windows PC with a colleague at office.
I've added a few rsa ssh keys while playing around with git, github, heroku and a few others.

What'd be the best way to remove all my credentials from my Windows PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mmc.exe application to manage the installed certificates.  Start : Run... mmc.exe and add the Certificates plugin.  The GUI will show you all the installed certificates and allow you to export/remove them.

Comment: ``certmgr.msc``

Answer (score 2):

SSH keys have no standard location. If you generated them using OpenSSH's `ssh-keygen` or PuTTY's PuTTYgen, all you need is to delete the key files you created. (OpenSSH keeps them in `~/.ssh/` by default.)

---

Don't forget a free-space wipe (`cipher /w:C:\` will do).