# How to uninstall completely an application on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

After a remote repo was renamed, Github Desktop doesn't let me push to or pull from it: it prompts me for credentials and that fails every time. Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't help. Thing is, when I reinstall it I has all my settings already which means Windows did NOT uninstall if completely.

How can I uninstall it completely, with settings and everything?

Comment: This likely has less to do with the application and more to do with the config files _(GitHub Desktop installs to `%LocalAppData%\GitHubDesktop`)_

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please [edit] the question to ask about the problem you're trying to solve, rather than applying your idea of a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all the keys (credentials) from a PC](https://superuser.com/questions/245932/remove-all-the-keys-credentials-from-a-pc)

Comment: Try [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/).

Comment: `Windows did NOT uninstall if completely` .. this has nothing to do with Windows and everything to do with GitHubDesktop.  Microsoft does not control what installation or un-installation programs do.